# localhost runs site extremely slow

Tags: performance

I have a Windows 7 computer running MAMP and it works fine, although still a little slow. I have been working on a Druapl site for a few months now and normal page load times are around 3 seconds. I also work from a macbook from time to time. I am used to transferring the database and all the files needed to make my Drupal site operate from one setup to another. My Macbook used to work properly but now its slow as all hell. I'm getting 10-15 second load times for every page.

Recap: Using MAMP on both machines, one is running Mac OSX Yosemite, and the other is Windows 7.

- Windows page load time is 3 seconds. Not bad, but not great.
- Mac page load time is 10 - 15 seconds. Horrible.

I have to use my macbook as it is portable and can be used for my upcoming presentation. It used to work fine but is now ridiculous to work with. I'm sure there could be more optimization and tweaks done to my drupal installation to make it faster, but that can't be the problem with my mac's load times.

Edit:

So I got my site to perform better yesterday. The steps made no sense and it obviously didnt fix the issue because starting work today,  the server was hanging on all page loads again. I increased my max memory usage in my php.ini, and now its back to normal page load times. I still dont trust it though and will keep updating this question if anything further happens. Thanks All!

Comment: Are you copying over settings.php between the 2 environments? Is it possible that the Mac environment is referencing your Windows machine DB remotely? (e.g. if both the Mac/Win7 machine are the same network).

Comment: They are both pointing to local setups. Its working now... weird. Thanks for the comment, definitely made me check that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Drupal 7 so slow?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow)

Comment: If you say performance is different on one server compared to another then it sounds like a server configuration issue, which is generally off topic here as it isn't really a drupal specific problem.

Comment: When I posted this question I thought the problem was coming from Drupal but it might not be, who knows. Cant have a Drupal site without the server or a million other points of failure...

Comment: I have to agree, server config itself is off topic here. If it's a Drupal-specific config issue that's one thing, but _Cant have a Drupal site without the server or a million other points of failure..._ doesn't hold weight I'm afraid. You can't sit at your desk to code your Drupal site without a chair, but we're not going to help you to fix a broken chair here :) The "might not be" is something you'd need to confirm at your end, it's not possible for us to make that assessment without access to the server

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can easily cause sudden big slowdowns like this is where a module or theme is removed from the code base without having been uninstalled in the database.  Drupal then goes searching for it by recursively searching though every possible folder that can contain a module on every page load.  This can easily add many seconds to page loads.

If you're synchronising code and DB with your windows environment then it's a possibility that this is the case.  you can confirm it by temporarily putting some kind of debugging in file_scan_directory() in includes/file.inc.  If it fires 100s (or 1000s) of times then that's probably the culprit.

If it is then re-syncing with your other environment may help.  Otherwise I'd recommend identifying the missing module, adding it to the code base again and if it's meant to not be there, disabling and then uninstalling it before deleting the files again.